# css background with 3 directions

Tags: css, background, linear-gradients

is it possible to create a background with 3 colors and 3 directions in CSS?
I'm a beginner with CSS gradients.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with only **one div** and multiple gradient and without the need to complicate with transform or negative margin:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background: 
  linear-gradient(150deg,#0c13a2 35%,transparent 35.5%),
  linear-gradient(-120deg, #000000 50%, #c70535 50.5%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```